# Where are Knox clone bricks made?

Tags: clone-brands

I bought a mix of LEGO pieces, that included some bricks with KNOX on studs - for example a 1×1 with KNOX on its stud, 2×3 & 2×4 with the logo on 1/2 of the studs. They have tubes like those used by LEGO but with hole going right through. Corners a little rounded. Also a brick like plate with tall hollow studs, guess holds better.

Where were they made?

Comment: What is the question? Can you post some pictures? There isn't enough here to have a discussion, let alone a Q&A.

Comment: The only thing I could find is [this](https://knoxandfloyd.com/shop/wooden-noblesse-143-piece-block-set/) wooden block set, but I'm pretty certain this isn't what OP has.

Answer (score 4):

I think this question is about [K'Nex bricks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%27Nex)

[image]

Comment: Yes, that is it. Looks like an O. I thought I'd fault with search engine when it came up with K'nex. Also some rods & their connector.